# Sum of the elements of two infinite sets

Tags: sequences-and-series

A={1,2,3,4...} and B={-2,-3,-4,-5...} are two sets. can we say that sum of all the elements of both sets is 1? 
I searched dir sımilar answers but; only found that rearrangement of divergent series can have different answers. But ı didn't get satisfied

Comment: Do you mean sum of all elements of both sets, as in $(1+2+3+4+...) + (-2 -3 -4 -...)$?

Comment: Absolutely not! For example, the terms in a convergent series must tend to $0$.

Comment: Yes I mean (1+2+3+4+5+6+....)+(-2-3-4-5-.....)